# Variables unknown when using rmarkdown::render

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When I render an RMD automatically calling `rmarkdown::render()` within an R-Script, I run into trouble when - within the RMD itself - I try to access list-variables. In the example I want to loop through the content of the list variable and render a table for each list.

The first chunk

````
# This works
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='show'}
knitr::kable(a[[1]])
```
````

within the RMD renders successfully. However, the second section chunk

````
# This doesn't work
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='show'}
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  knitr::kable(a[[i]])
}
````

doesn't evaluate at all. There is not even an error/warning. The complete output renders as follows:

[image]

How can I successfully render the second chunk, named 'This doesn't work'? I'd expect to see 3 lists here, displaying the numbers 1:10, 11:20, 21:30.

Reproducible example: Save the following script as `render.R`:

```
setwd("C:/path_to_your_script_location/")
# generate a list containing 3 lists
a <- list(list(tour_id=1:10), list(tour_id=11:20), list(tour_id=21:30))
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", output_dir = "./", output_file = "out_test.html",
                  encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = TRUE)
```

and save the following content as `test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: Test
author: "Author"
date: "May 9th, 2018"
output: html_document
---

# This works
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='show'}
knitr::kable(a[[1]])
```
# This doesn't work
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='show'}
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  knitr::kable(a[[i]])
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution: Change your last chunk to

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
 print(knitr::kable(a[[i]]))
}
```
````

Comment: Thanx! When using cat() instead of print() the solution works for me.